# Insert objects into a list

Tags: c++

Any kind soul know how to correct the following code

"d1.insert(d1.begin(), it[0]);" so the the output is as follow:

program will run successfuly and display: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> ostream & print(const T & start, const T & end)
{
    T tmp = start;
    for(; tmp != end; ++tmp)
    {
            cout<< *tmp<< " ";
    }
    return cout;
}
class A
{
public:
    int a;
public:
    A(int a):a(a) {}
    A(const A & a) {}
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & c, const A & o)
{
    c<<o.a;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int tab[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    list<A> l1(tab, tab+10);
    deque<A> d1;
    list<A>::iterator it;
    for(it = l1.begin(); it != l1.end(); ++it)
    {
            d1.insert(d1.begin(), it[0]);
    }
    print(d1.begin(), d1.end())<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does it display the list correctly or not? Can you use `std::copy` here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems from the code that you want to insert to a `std::deque` not a `std::list` (you already inserted the array values into the list `l1`). You could follow the same procedure to insert to the `std::deque`:

```
int main(void) {
    int tab[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    std::list<int> l1(tab, tab + 10);
    std::deque<int> d1(tab, tab + 10);
}
```

where I have simply replaced `A` by `int` here as the former looks just to be a wrapper for an `int`.

Alternatively you could do,

```
int main(void) {
    int tab[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    std::list<int> l1(tab, tab + 10);
    std::deque<int> d1;

    auto it = d1.begin();
    d1.insert(it, l1.begin(), l1.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is just to use `std::copy`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
//...
std::copy(l1.begin(), l1.end(), std::back_inserter(d1));
```

There are other issues with your code you should correct:

1) Remove the empty `A` copy constructor.  By making it empty, you're creating `A` copies that will not copy the `a` member.

2) The parameter to the `A` constructor should be different than the name of the member variable.

[See the Live Example](http://ideone.com/REY3bf)